# Angularjs change ng-model value with conditions on binding value

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue with ng-model in angularjS. I have this piece of code :

```
<select ng-model="node[col.field]">
    <option selected="selected">-</option>
    <option>I</option>
    <option>W</option>
    <option>E</option>
</select>
```

For example, When the user selects "I", I'd like to have node[col.field] = "1" and not node[col.field] = "I". Is that possible to do that ?

Comment: set `value=1` in `<option>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the value attribute of option. I feel you can declare what really every option should mean and then you might be able of using your method.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

Comment: Thanks it works, i didn't think about it. Just one question to be sure that I understood. When you put "value" one the option tag, ng-model value is binded with this value and not with what the displayed value ?

Comment: Yes that is right! But it is not an angular specific solution, adding the value attribute works for any JavaScript need since the Dom element will use the value attribute first before the displayed value

Comment: Great ! I got it, Thanks for your answers.